Navigation bar SwiftUI toolbar background
I set up my nav bar like this:
        .navigationTitle(selectedTab == .users ? "Working with GET request" : "Working with POST request")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbarBackground(UIConstraints.primary, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)

get this:

but I don't want yellow color to go all the way to the top where wifi and battery icons will be, I want it to stop before the line on the top
I am struggling to formulate a question about this and find any info, please advise

AFAIK, .toolbarBackground(for: .navigationBar) always overwhelms statusBar too. So you may want to try this approach by setting UINavigationBar.appearance():
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }
   
    var body: some View {
        ...
        //.toolbarBackground(UIConstraints.primary, for: .navigationBar)
        //.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
    }
}

Output:


If you add a tiny amount of top padding to the NavigationStack then this breaks the contact with the safe area inset. The toolbar background then won't extend to the top of the screen.

I think the padding needs to equate to at least 1 pixel. 0.1 is not enough, but 0.5 works.

You probably don't want to add any padding if there is no top area inset. This may be the case on devices in landscape orientation. A GeometryReader can be used to measure the inset size.


var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        NavigationStack {
            Text("hello")
                .navigationTitle("Working with GET request")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbarBackground(.yellow)
                .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        }
        .padding(.top, proxy.safeAreaInsets.top > 0 ? 0.5 : 0)
    }
}



Thank you, this actually helped more, but I will have to accept another answer as it fits more to the question
